# Some extra tags while doing update based on a result set

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Basically, I want to upate .nid with .id when coll2 has coll1.id in its abclist

```js
db.<coll1>.find().forEach( function(elem) {
    db.<coll1>.update (
        {_id : elem._id },
        { "$set" : { 
            nid : db.<coll2>.aggregate ( [
                {"$unwind" : "$abclist" } ,
                {"$match" : { "abclist" : elem._id } },
                {"$project" : { _id :1 } } ] 
            )
        }}
    )
})
```

When I do the below part separately

```js
db.<coll2>.aggregate ([
    { "$unwind" : "$abclist" } ,
    { "$match" : { "abclist" : elem._id } },
    {"$project" : { _id :1 } } 
])
```

I get the nice response with just the object id.

But when done in the above update statement, by nid gets updated as below with extra firstBatch/_cursor etc etc

```js
"nid" : { "_firstBatch" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("539ebded1c70fac84cd17510") } ], "_cursor" : {  } } }
```

Any idea how to avoid.

Thanks
Sathya

Comment: Can you be a little more clear in what you are trying to do please? What you think you are doing is not what is really happening. You are not sending these "nested" statement to the server at once. The aggregate is evaluating and returning a result that is then sent to your query. It seems like you want to extract the `_id` values from that response though.

Comment: Yes. Basically, I want to update one collection with the object id of other collection when the second collections linkedids array has the the object id passed.